# Getting broker configuration via kafka-configs.sh

Tags: apache-kafka

I set up AWS MSK, but it does not have a GUI to view the server configuration. I tried using the kafka-configs.sh, but it didn't output anything useful.

`./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server {HOST} --entity-default --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 --describe`

Output:
`Configs for broker 1 are:`

I tried doing this on my local kafka and am getting the same value. What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a known behavior: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7720

Currently this tool only shows configurations that have been dynamically overridden.

To see all broker configs, you have 2 options:

- Use the [`AdminClient.describeConfigs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-) API
- Tweak the ConfigCommand.scala tool. Just remove the filter on https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/ad26914de65e2db244fbe36a2a5fd03de87dfb79/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConfigCommand.scala#L347

---

Update: This issue is being addressed by [KIP-524](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-524%3A+Allow+users+to+choose+config+source+when+describing+configs) which is currently targetted for Kafka 2.5

Comment: Thanks for the info @MickaelMaison, you saved me some time. I kept trying the command Hsien mentioned, with different options/values like an idiot.